# firefox crashes if it doesn't find the favicon on the first link vue2/nuxt

Tags: vue.js, firefox, browser, nuxt.js, favicon

I'm still struggling with the favicons. I need one basic one. If it's available on the server, it's it, if not, it's the basic one. I write it in the nxt config.

After building in the folder dist mb placed 3 icons. Since at the moment of building it may not be there, I write the path in the page component.

This is how it works: if we put something in dist, we put it in. If we have not put anything, we first go to the server and get the server one. If it is not located/available, then already basic from the folder, which is always available.

In chrome/edge everything seems to work as it should. But faerfox makes problems. If at least one of the resources is unavailable, it simply refuses to install anything. How to overcome it? What is the best way to add these icons?

simply adding multiple links doesn't work in firefox. It either finds the first one or crashes.